# Can I simply append youtube embed code with jQuery or should I use AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, youtube, embed, frontend

I need to dynamically load a youtube embed video on one of my sites and I was wondering if the following technique, using jQuery, would be acceptable :

```
var video_html = '<p class="x">X</p><iframe width="650" height="385" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/embed_url" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$('element').append(video_html);
```

Is there a reason why I should use Ajax instead ?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is used when you need to call a service. I think ajax is not needed here. 
Also you can just change the src of the iframe:

```
$('#iframeId').attr('src', '//www.youtube.com/new_video_url');
```

Comment: Ok thanks ! So if I don't need to call a script in order to generate the output, a simple .append() will do the trick.